# Intercepter (la direction de) mon regard

Tags: expressions

Bonjour,

A observe B. C le remarque. A pense :

> C se redresse en **interceptant la direction** de mon regard.

Est-il possible d'écrire *intercepter la direction de mon regard* ou seul *intercepter mon regard* est correct ?

Comment: Larousse: Suivre le regard de quelqu'un, regarder dans la même direction que lui. Suivre le regard de quelqu'un, ***regarder dans la même direction que lui***.

Answer (score 4):

***Intercepter le regard** de quelqu'un* signifie percevoir quelque chose de particulier dans son regard, le plus souvent en se mettant dans son axe de vision et parfois même en le forçant à nous regarder dans les yeux.

> [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/intercepter)  Prendre connaissance de ce qui est adressé à quelqu'un d'autre. [...] *Elle dut comprendre, intercepter un regard de mon père (Françoise Sagan, *Bonjour tristesse*, 1954, p. 45).*

C'est possiblement une métaphore sur l'interception du courrier qui consiste à prendre connaissance du contenu d'une lettre, voire aujourd'hui d'un courriel, destinés à quelqu'un d'autre.

J'éviterais *intercepter la direction* qui a moins de sens, une direction ne pouvant pas être affectée par une quelconque interception. On peut lui substituer ***deviner** la direction d'un regard*, *la **remarquer***, *la **découvrir***, *la **surprendre***, etc.

Comment: suivre  un regard.

Answer (score 1):

« Intercepter une direction »,  n'a  de signification que si l'on considère « direction » comme signifiant « ligne droite », ce qui était la pratique en mathématiques par le passé.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/direction)) 1. [Dans l'espace] Ligne − en principe − droite qu'une personne se propose de suivre ou suivant laquelle un corps mobile ou un objet qui se déplace, se dirige ou est dirigé. Toutes directions (panneau indicateur de la circulation routière).
> ♦ Le chien repart à fond de train dans la direction qu'Anna a prise (Claudel, Tobie,1940, III, 2, p. 1264)

« Intercepter »,  n'a concrètement que le sens mathématique de « avoir (au moins ) un point en commun avec une figure donnée », mis à part des sens spéciaux comme  dans « intercepter un avion » et « intercepter le ballon », ou « boucher, obstruer » ([intercepter](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/intercepter)).

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/intercepter))− GÉOM. **Intercepter un arc**. Couper un arc, avoir une intersection avec lui. Deux parallèles interceptent entre elles, sur la circonférence, des arcs égaux (Hadamard, Géom. plane,1898, p. 55).Deux arcs égaux sont interceptés par des angles au centre égaux (Roux, Miellou, Géom.,1946, p. 14).

On dit intercepter « un segment », « un cercle », « une ellipse », etc., « un axe », « une ligne droite », « une  droite »,  « une demi droite », « une courbe », etc.

Si ce sens-là était celui de « direction » dans « intercepter la direction du regard », cette expression serait absurde. Il ne peut donc s'agir que de « direction » dans le sens de « orientation » ([direction, Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_(g%C3%A9om%C3%A9trie))), ce qui résulte aussi en une absurdité.

« Intercepter le regard » n'a aucun sens que l'on puisse dériver du sens concret ou des sens spéciaux de « intercepter » : il n'y a aucun point d'interception, aucune submission du regard de l'autre.

Même selon le sens un peu spécial du [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/intercepter) (arrêter), « intercepter » ne convient pas ; que signifierait « arrêter le regard de quelqu'un » dans ce sens élémentaire de « arrêter ». On peut utiliser « arrêter » dans le sens suivant.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/arr%C3%AAter)) **Arrêter le regard** Le retenir
> ♦ Cette femme aux traits réguliers, épaisse, lourde, à la voix bête, est marquée du signe de celles qui n'arrêtent pas un regard, qui ne fixent pas une pensée. Elle me semble belle, pourtant, au long de ces nuits, d'une beauté étrangère à elle-même, empruntée à son désespoir. N'existe-t-il un homme que cet incendie attirerait? Mauriac, Le Nœud de Vipères,1932, p. 292.

- A pense « C se redresse, son regard étant arrêté par le mien »